# SQL Server: future values on column based on distinct rows of the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

[image]

I now want that `level1` future values are completed by doing the previous `level1` value minus the `level2`.

An example:

`level1` at 2019-12-11 00:00 = 2359,11 - 7,74 = 2351,37

`level1` at 2019-12-11 01:00 = 2351,37 - 7,74 = 2353,63

and so on.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't post data as an image; it makes it very difficult for us to help you unless you expect us to transcribe the data (which you should not). I don't follow your question either, especially as some of the values are truncated in your image. When you change your image tto `text` (or DDL and DML statements), please do show us your expected results as well, along with your attempt(s) and explain your logic.

Comment: @Larnu, I don't like it either, but I was not able to past a table here in stackoverflow, even when I converted it to markdown and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the last value of `level1` and then the cumulative values of `level2`.

If I assume that `level1` is non-increasing, then one method is:

```
select t.*,
       min(level1) over () - sum(level2) over (order by date) as new_value
from t;
```

If you need to actually find the previous non-null value of `level1`, you can also do that.  Here is a method using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (max(level1) over (partition by last_level1_date) -
        sum(level2) over (order by date)
       ) as new_value
from (select t.*,
             max(case when level1 is not null then date end) over (order by date) as last_level1_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

Oh, this would be simpler if SQL Server supported `IGNORE NULL`s on `LAG()` and/or `LAST_VALUE()`.